# Range box wires only

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

Wiring a new range when your box had three wires and no plug. I have a new Kitchenaid induction range.  My old range was directly wired with no plug. Wires were twisted together and a nut was placed where they joined. How can I use the wires and plug in a 3 or 4 prong plug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard wiring a 4-wire oven to 3-wire outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145817/hard-wiring-a-4-wire-oven-to-3-wire-outlet)

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box the old range was wired to?

Comment: It's quite possible your old box *was* grounded and the last person connected the range 3-wire because they didn't know it.  That's why we're interested in pix.